# Is there a method for creating a mutli-index dataframe from this specific dictionary that maintains the integrity of the data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multi-index

I have the following dictionary that I want to convert into a multi-index (on the columns) DataFrame:

```
fdict = {}
fdict['apple'] = {}
fdict['banana'] = {}

fdict['apple']['green'] = 5
fdict['apple']['red'] = 3
fdict['banana']['light_yellow'] = 10
fdict['appraisal round'] = 1

fdict

{'apple': {'green': 5, 'red': 3},
 'banana': {'light_yellow': 10},
 'appraisal round': 1}
```

I have managed to convert this to the multi-index (on the columns) DataFrame that I want as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

fruit_array = []
quality_array = []
values_array = []
for key in [key for key in fdict.keys() if key != 'appraisal round']:

    keys = fdict[key].keys()
    fr_array = np.repeat(key,len(keys))
    fruit_array.extend(fr_array)
    quality_array.extend(keys)
    val_array = fdict[key].values()
    values_array.extend(val_array)

columns_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([fruit_array,quality_array])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.reshape(values_array,(1,len(values_array))),columns=columns_index,index=[fdict['appraisal round']])

df

    apple       banana
    green   red light_yellow
1   5       3   10
```

I have one specific concern about this method that is (from what I understand) dictionaries are not specifically ordered (unless you use and ordered dict which I would prefer not to use here) and I am extrracting the data in a loop into arrays the order of which is important for the construction of the resulting DataFrame.  I need a method that maintains the integrity of the data link without relying on the fact that the data will be extracted in the right order.

So, is there a preferred method that explicitly maintains the key, value pair relationships in the dictionary whilst creating the DataFrame from it?  Also, less lines of code, would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`dict`s maintain insertion ordering in python 3.6+. But instead of worrying about that, it's better to unnest your dictionary so that it's more suitable for a MultiIndex. A MultiIndex simply has tuples for the keys so we can create that.

```
md = {(k1, k2) : v for k1,d in fdict.items() if k1 != 'appraisal round'
                   for k2,v in d.items()}

pd.DataFrame(md, index=[fdict['appraisal round']])
#  apple           banana
#  green red light_yellow
#1     5   3           10
```